# how display data using nested switch case?

Tags: android

[diagram of my project]

### act=1

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
      lisdis.setAdapter(adapter); 
      lisdis.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(display_publishermagazine.this, display_publicationmagazine.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("position", position+1);
        startActivity(mIntent);
```

### act=2

```
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("position",0);

   switch (intValue)
    {
        case 1:values = new String[] { "Android For Beginer","Android Devloper" };break;
        case 2:values = new String[] { "I-phone for beginer","I-phone for devloper" };break;
        case 3:values = new String[] { "windows for beginer","windows for devloper" };break;
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

lisdis.setAdapter(adapter); 
    lisdis.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(display_publishermagazine.this, display_publicationmagazine.class);


    myIntent.putExtra("position", position+1);
    startActivity(myIntent);
   }
```

### act3

```
      Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
      int intValue = myIntent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    switch (intValue)
    {
        case 1:values = new String[] { "Android for lerner1","android for learner2" };break;
        case 2:values = new String[] { "Android  for devloper1","android for devloper2" };break;
    }

/*values = new String[] { "iphone for lerner1","iphone for learner2" }      
values = new String[] { "iphone for devloper1","iphone for devloper2} */
}

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        g1.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

I need to

- display data in another activity using switch case when user click on android
- then display data android Lerner or android developers.then  click on android learner
- then display android lerner1 or android learner2
- and when select android developer then display android lerner1 or android learner2.

Here it works for only android not work for iphone or window.

Comment: I really try to understand what do you want to reach but I'm not able to understand. What kind of data do you want to display? Do you want to display objects from your String array? Can you be more specific?

Comment: thanks dear.yes i want to display a data from string array in to the lisview when click any data from list view then appropriate id pass to another activity and display  appropriate data in listview.

Comment: example when click on android--->android for lerner--->android lerner 1,android learner2 same for iphone or android.sorry for this type language.all data are view in list view.i m developing my academic project i have only basic idea for android.my application is magazine reader which display category vise data above is categories.

Comment: OK if I understand you correctly. Let's say you have ActivityA and there's ListView1 with String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile"}; and ActivityB contains also ListView2 where do you want bind data e.g. I click Android in ActivityA and String[]  "Android for lerner1","android for learner2" will be binded in ActivityB's ListView2? Am I right?

Comment: yes.but i only handle android categories using switch case.iPhone or windows not. i have three acti.1){ "Android", "iPhone", "Windows Mobile"}; show in list view. then act.2)new String[] { "Android For Begin er","Android Developer" } and act.3)String[] { "Android for lerner1","android for learner2" } .

Answer (score 0):

How about this

Usage: `TutorialUtils.getMenu();`, `TutorialUtils.getMenu(new int[] { 0 })`, `TutorialUtils.getMenu(new int[] { 2, 1 })` or in your case with some modifications `TutorialUtils.getMenu(getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("positionsHistory"))`.

`TutorialUtils` Class, handle exceptions yourself.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TutorialUtils {
private static CompositeTutorialNode nodes = new CompositeTutorialNode(
        "root");
static {
    nodes = new CompositeTutorialNode("root")
            .add(new CompositeTutorialNode("Android").add(
                    new CompositeTutorialNode("Android For Developers").add(
                            new TextTutorialNode("Android for Developer1"))
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode(
                                    "Android for Developer2"))).add(
                    new CompositeTutorialNode("Android For Learners").add(
                            new TextTutorialNode("Android for Learner1"))
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode(
                                    "Android for Learner2"))))
            .add(new CompositeTutorialNode("iPhone Sucks !!")
                    .add(new CompositeTutorialNode("iPhone Sucks For Developers")
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode(
                                    "iPhone Sucks for Developer1")).add(
                                    new TextTutorialNode(
                                            "iPhone Sucks for Developer2")))
                    .add(new CompositeTutorialNode("iPhone For Learners")
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode("iPhone Sucks for Learner1"))
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode("iPhone Sucks for Learner2"))))
            .add(new CompositeTutorialNode("Windows").add(
                    new CompositeTutorialNode("Windows For Developers").add(
                            new TextTutorialNode("Windows for Developer1"))
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode(
                                    "Windows for Developer2"))).add(
                    new CompositeTutorialNode("Windows For Learners").add(
                            new TextTutorialNode("Windows for Learner1"))
                            .add(new TextTutorialNode(
                                    "Windows for Learner2"))));

}

public static String[] getMenu() {
    TutorialNode tmpNode = nodes;
    return prepareNames(tmpNode);
}

private static String[] prepareNames(TutorialNode node) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (node instanceof CompositeTutorialNode) {
        List<TutorialNode> childs = ((CompositeTutorialNode) node).get();
        for (TutorialNode n : childs) {
            names.add(n.getName());
        }
    }
    return names.toArray(new String[] {});
}

public static String[] getMenu(int[] position) {
    TutorialNode tmpNode = nodes;
    for (int i : position) {
        if (tmpNode instanceof CompositeTutorialNode) {
            tmpNode = ((CompositeTutorialNode) tmpNode).get(i);
        }
    }
    return prepareNames(tmpNode);
}

interface TutorialNode {

    public String getName();
}

public static class CompositeTutorialNode implements TutorialNode {
    private List<TutorialNode> childs = new ArrayList<TutorialNode>();
    String name;

    public CompositeTutorialNode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CompositeTutorialNode add(TutorialNode node) {
        childs.add(node);
        return this;
    }

    public TutorialNode get(int index) {
        return childs.get(index);
    }

    public List<TutorialNode> get() {
        return childs;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static class TextTutorialNode implements TutorialNode {
    String name;

    public TextTutorialNode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you dear.in this tutorial i cant understand how use this tutorial.i have only basic knowledge about android i m learner.plz tell how it use

Comment: put this class in your project and then do following changes in your act 1 code : use this `String[] values = TutorialUtils.getMenu();` and also in `onItemClick` do this `ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();` `positions.add(position);` `mIntent.putExtra("positions", positions);`
act 2 code : `String[] values = TutorialUtils.getMenu(getIntent().getIntegerArrayList("positions"));` in act 2's onClick method just add another position in bundle that user has selected and pass it to act 3.
act 3 code: fill your self.

Comment: you may need to modify `public static String[] getMenu(int[] position)` to take `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `int[]`.

Comment: thanks you dear for your help.i try but i cant.it gives error.